# Отладка пользовательских элементов управления без добавления на форму

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток, имеется библиотека пользовательских элементов управления для основного приложения, когда-то давно припоминаю что можно было запускать отладку выбранного элемента так сказать в real-time непосредственно в студии без добавления на форму, или я с чем-то путаю, будьте так любезны освежите память:)

Comment: Вы путаете `XAML` редактор с отладкой. Во время разработки, у вас не должно в редакторе запускаться что либо. Там должно быть лишь визуальное представление объекта. Если в вашем случае у вас все работает в редакторе, то вам стоит задуматься о правильности написания класса.

Comment: @Yami К сожалению я не путаю XAML редактор с отладкой. Извиняюсь вставил неправильный тег, элементы управления WinForms.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под отладкой элемента? вроде бы в дизайнере можно посмотреть только как контролы при ресайзе себя будут вести (если речь все таки про винформы) И то только те вещи которые заданы в дизайнере, если вы например пропишите анкоры в клиентском коде, то в дизайнере, естественно, эффекта не увидите.

Comment: @yolosora под отладкой я понимаю запуск отладки по F5, я может путаю с чем-то дело в том что я кодил только закончив универ (это было лет 7 назад), может это была и не студия не помню. Помню запускал проект (DLL) открывалось окно и можно было выбрать конкретный компонент в библиотеке  и данный компонент выполнялся в реальном времени отдельно..

Answer (score 0):

Понял о чем вы, здесь есть два варианта действий в зависимости от того чего вы хотите.

**Если хотите просто посмотреть как работает контрол**

1) Пкм по вашей библиотеке контролов
2) Отладка
3) Запустить новый экземпляр
4) Выбираем интересный контрол, отлаживаем

**Если хотите отлаживать в дизайн-тайме**

1) Пкм по вашей библиотеке контролов
2) Сделать автозапускаемым проектом
3) Свойства -> Отладка -> Запуск внешней программы -> Выбираем студию
4) Жмем F5, в открывшемся новом окне студии открываем решение в котором хотим использовать эти контролы
5) Начинаем дизайнить, в первом окне студии расставляем брейкпоинты, смотрим что происходит, радуемся!